# What happened to the Speakeasy computational environment?

Tags: software

After reading his interview with the [Computer History Museum](http://archive.computerhistory.org/resources/access/text/2013/12/102746804-05-01-acc.pdf) , Cleve Moler (creator of MATLAB), mentioned that the Speakeasy Computational Environment was a precursor to MATLAB, and served as some inspiration to the original version of the system. After doing some further research, I have discovered that the Speakeasy system was written in a language called Mortran, was heavily used at the Federal Reserve, and was most recently updated in [2006](http://web.archive.org/web/20060105054517/http://speakeasy.com/). Given that this system originated in 1960 at Argonne National Laboratory, this would make Speakeasy one of the first interactive numerical systems, like APL. Could someone provide me some information as to the current status of the Speakeasy system, and if it could potentially be made available as either a freeware, open source, or if a source code listing of the Mortran code is available?

Comment: Oh something new. I like that.

Comment: I met Stanley Cohen at a meeting at Argonne a million years ago (1980's); he was quite pleased with himself, gave me a card, showing me that he had a Japanese name on the back side, pointing to the telephone number and saying gleefully "You can get in touch with me here, but my secretary will never let you through." I never did try, but I do vaguely remember finding mortran somehow and trying to run speakeasy since it was available at nuclear physics labs and we had just gotten a shiny new VAX 780 and a whole bunch of VT-100's...

Comment: Well, you have to know someone who knows the secret password...